# Control query execution in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, orm, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Can we control the execution of composite query set in mongoengine?

For example:

```
from models import X
Xobjs = X.objects.filter(field1='xyz')  # query 1
Xobjs1 = Xobjs.filter(field2='pqr')     # query 2
Xobjs2 = Xobjs1.filter(field3='abc')    # query 3
```

Now I want to the use the result of ***Xobj2***.

The ORM can do this in 2 ways:

- It can fetch the data from persistent storage by executing query 1 into the memory and then latter apply query 2 and query 3 on this data to give me the result.
- It can create a complex composite query under the hood and delay the execution of query 1, query 2 and when I use ***Xobj2*** it execute this composite query(made by query 1,2 and 3) and get the data from persistent storage.

I see the code of mongoengine and found out that it use the second method. Now my question is if we can force mongoengine to execute query 1 and then apply subsequent queries on the data available in main memory after executing query 1?

Comment: I doubt 1 is possible, because mongoengine would have to mirror MongoDB's query engine, supporting all the operators, etc. Plus, if the result set of 1 is large, it would be way slower than option 2 and everyone would be asking for option 2 instead. Why do you want option 2?

Comment: So I am just curious because may be I want to perform some operation on the data in RAM than executing a very complex query on actual persistent store. So there can be situation where such a trade off can exist. So I want to exploit such a trade off.